Generated ui_mainwindow.h file is not finding created subclass headers for promoted widgets
I created a subclass of QTextEdit called TextEditEvents. The purpose of this subclass is simply to capture keypress events and then send a signal back to my main window controller to do a thing with those signals.
So I implemented the subclass, and then promoted my original 'input' QTextEdit to the next class in the UI designer. Now on compile I am receiving this error:
In file included from .../mainwindow.cpp:2:
.../ui_mainwindow.h:22:10: fatal error: texteditevents.h: No such file or directory
Then upon navigating to the generated ui_mainwindow.h file I again see the same error on the included file.
Error Screenshot 1
Error Screenshot 2
I have double and triple checked that my header name is correct on the promoted QWidget (and in the generated ui_mainwindow.h file).
I have changed my build path to be outside of my project directory (level above).
I have ensured I have
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

all included in my CMakeList.txt
I have ensured that the texteditevents class files (.cpp and .h) are included in my CMakeList.txt file.
Here is the relevant excerpt from my CMakeList.txt file.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(EvanderCradle VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Network)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        mainwindow.cpp
        mainwindow.h
        mainwindow.ui
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(EvanderCradle
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        apiclient.h apiclient.cpp
        serializer.h serializer.cpp
        resources.qrc
        texteditevents.h texteditevents.cpp
    )

Finally, here is what my configuration for the promoted QTextEdit widget looks like:
Promoted QTextEdit Widget
Overall Window Layout

Which folder contains the texteditevents.h file? Add that in an include_diretories() or target_include_directories() so your compiler can find it.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Look up how to make a plugin for form designer which would add new widget to toolbar. The generated code didn't knew to include proper headers.
If you are a pervert who edit .ui files manually, the .ui file have to contain a section:
<customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>YourTextEditSubclass</class>
   <extends>QTextEdit</extends>
   <header>YourTextEditSubclass.h</header>
  </customwidget>
  <!-- other customwidgets -->
</customwidgets>

If custom class is a container like a QFrame, it must have <container>1</container> property. Manual editing of forms is quite non-trivial.
The header file should be at location manually specified in project. There is no automated way to detect where it came from, which makes .ui file separated from implementations of customized widgets.

I edit my ui files manually all the time because a lot of the forms I have for the research we do are very repetitive. Also for adding the same custom widgets to a different form its easier to copy text from one ui to another.

@drescherjm You can insert whole form into several while using separate .ui file, if the form's top widget is a qframe. I know our team did that somehow.

I do that often.
